# How to make my shell recognize the last output

Tags: python, matplotlib

My code is printing about a couple of hundreds of lines in one go and I need to way for it to be less. So my code can output 4 things, Over Under Neither Problem. I'd like to make the code so its looks at what it printed before and if it's the same, then not print it, but if it's different then print it.

Here is my code if you want to try to solve it!

```
import yfinance as yf
import mplfinance as mpf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import pandas as pd

# Dates to get stock data
start_date = "2010-07-01"
end_date = "2023-06-19"

# Fetch Tesla stock data
tesla_data = yf.download("TSLA", start=start_date, end=end_date)
tesla_weekly_data = tesla_data.resample("W").agg(
    {"Open": "first", "High": "max", "Low": "min", "Close": "last", "Volume": "sum"}
).dropna()

# Get the latest closing price
latest_price = tesla_weekly_data['Close'][-1]

# Calculate the EMA with different lengths
ema_lengths = [8, 13, 21, 55]
ema_colors = ['blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'red']
ema_lines = []
for length, color in zip(ema_lengths, ema_colors):
    ema_line = tesla_weekly_data['Close'].ewm(span=length, adjust=False).mean()
    ema_lines.append(ema_line)

# Create additional plot
apds = []
close_price = tesla_weekly_data['Close']
apds.append(mpf.make_addplot(close_price, color='cyan', width=2))

# Add EMA lines
for ema_line, color in zip(ema_lines, ema_colors):
    apds.append(mpf.make_addplot(ema_line, color=color))

# Plot the candlestick chart with EMA lines
fig, axes = mpf.plot(tesla_weekly_data,
                     type='candle',
                     addplot=apds,
                     style='yahoo',
                     title='Tesla Stock Prices',
                     ylabel='Price',
                     volume=True,
                     ylabel_lower='Volume',
                     volume_panel=1,
                     figsize=(16, 8),
                     returnfig=True,
                     warn_too_much_data=2800,
                     )

# Move the y-axis labels to the left side
axes[0].yaxis.tick_left()
axes[1].yaxis.tick_left()

# Adjust the position of the y-axis label for price
axes[0].yaxis.set_label_coords(-0.08, 0.5)

# Adjust the position of the y-axis label for volume
axes[1].yaxis.set_label_coords(-0.08, 0.5)

# Set y-axis label for price and volume
axes[0].set_ylabel('Price', rotation=0, labelpad=20)
axes[1].set_ylabel('Volume', rotation=0, labelpad=20)

# Make the legend box
handles = axes[0].get_legend_handles_labels()[0]
red_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='red')
green_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='green')
cyan_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='cyan')
handles = handles[:2] + [red_patch, green_patch, cyan_patch]
labels = ["Price Up", "Price Down", "Closing Price"]
axes[0].legend(handles=handles, labels=labels)

# Add a box to display the current price
latest_price_text = f"Current Price: ${latest_price:.2f}"
box_props = dict(boxstyle='round', facecolor='white', edgecolor='black', alpha=0.8)
axes[0].text(0.02, 0.95, latest_price_text, transform=axes[0].transAxes,
             fontsize=12, verticalalignment='top', bbox=box_props)

# Function to create hover annotations
def hover_annotations(data):
    annot_visible = False
    annot = axes[0].text(0, 0, '', visible=False, ha='left', va='top')

    def onmove(event):
        nonlocal annot_visible
        nonlocal annot

        if event.inaxes == axes[0]:
            index = int(event.xdata)
            if index >= len(data.index):
                index = -1
            elif index < 0:
                index = 0
            values = data.iloc[index]
            mytext = (f"{values.name.date().strftime('%m/%d/%Y'):}\n"+
                      f"O: {values['Open']:.2f}\n"+
                      f"H: {values['High']:.2f}\n"+
                      f"L: {values['Low']:.2f}\n"+
                      f"C: {values['Close']:.2f}\n"+
                      f"V: {values['Volume']:.0f}"
                     )

            annot_visible = True
        else:
            mytext = ''
            annot_visible = False

        annot.set_position((event.xdata, event.ydata))
        annot.set_text(mytext)
        annot.set_visible(annot_visible)
        fig.canvas.draw_idle()

    fig.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', onmove)

    return annot

# Attach hover annotations to the plot
annotations = hover_annotations(tesla_weekly_data)

# Get the lines' data points
lines = axes[0].get_lines()

linecyan = None  # Variable to store the leftmost point of Line 1
lineblue = None  # Variable to store the leftmost point of Line 2
linegreen = None  # Variable to store the leftmost point of Line 3
lineyellow = None  # Variable to store the leftmost point of Line 4
linered = None  # Variable to store the leftmost point of Line 5

# Get the x-values from the DataFrame index
x = tesla_weekly_data.index

# Save space in shell
recent = None

# Iterate over x-values
for x_value in x:
    x_index = tesla_weekly_data.index.get_loc(x_value)
    for line in lines:
        if line.get_color() == 'cyan':
            y_data = line.get_ydata()
            linecyan = y_data[x_index]
            
        if line.get_color() == 'blue':
            y_data = line.get_ydata()
            lineblue = y_data[x_index]
            
        if line.get_color() == 'green':
            y_data = line.get_ydata()
            linegreen = y_data[x_index]
            
        if line.get_color() == 'yellow':
            y_data = line.get_ydata()
            lineyellow = y_data[x_index]
            
        if line.get_color() == 'red':
            y_data = line.get_ydata()
            linered = y_data[x_index]

    # Print the leftmost point at each iteration
    first = linegreen
    second = lineyellow
    third = lineblue
    fourth = linered

    if linered > linegreen:
        if linered > lineyellow:
            if linered > lineblue:
                print("Line Red is Over all 3 other lines at x =", x_value)
            else:
                print("Line Red is not over or under all 3 other lines at x =", x_value)
        else:
            print("Line Red is not over or under all 3 other lines at x =", x_value)
    elif linered < linegreen:
        if linered < lineyellow:
            if linered < lineblue:
                print("Line Red is Under all 3 other lines at x =", x_value)
            else:
                print("Line Red is not over or under all 3 other lines at x =", x_value)
        else:
            print("Line Red is not over or under all 3 other lines at x =", x_value)
    else:
        print("Problem!")

    print("---------------------")

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

Comment: If @Daniel Goldfarb's answer works, you should accept their answer. You have asked 5 questions since creating your account but have not accepted any of the answers to the 4 questions that have answers. If the answers don't work, then comment on them to clarify the issue. Please accept answers to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

> i've tried to make a code so its looks at what it printed before and if it's the same to not print it but if it's different to print it ...

The simplest way to do something like this is to *not* call print directly, but rather to create your own printing function that keeps track of what was printed.  To keep it simple also, pass in only strings, thus ...

```py
printed = []
def myprint( print_this ):
    nonlocal printed
    if print_this in printed:
        return

    printed.append(print_this)
    print(print_this)
```

So now, for example, instead of:

```py
print("Line Red is Over all 3 other lines at x =", x_value)
```

you would write:

```
myprint(f"Line Red is Over all 3 other lines at x = ${x_value:.2f}")
```

The above is not super efficient, if you have a lot of different things to print, and are doing so many times, however it is probably efficient enough for what appears to be your purposes.  It can easily be made more efficient if needed, by storing the strings in a hash table, instead of just a list.

---

---

If the value (`x_value`) at the end of your printout is not part of what makes something "already printed" ... In other words, for example, you only want to see `"Line Red is Over all 3 other lines at x ="` once even if the code tries to print it for multiple values of x, then there are two simple versions you can do:

1. either save only the first part of the string (for example `printed.append(print_this[0:20])` and the check then becomes `if print_this[0:20] in printed:`, or
2. pass another variable into `myprint()` that gets saved instead of the string itself, for example:

```py
def myprint( case, print_this ):
    nonlocal printed
    if case in printed:
        return
    printed.append(case)
    print(print_this)
```

then

```py
myprint( 1, f"Line Red is Over all 3 other lines at x = ${x_value:.2f}")
```

and

```py
myprint( 2, f"Line Red is not over or under all 3 other lines at x = ${x_value:.2f}")
```